# Altium gerber file question

Tags: altium

I am doing my first altium project and I got this weird top overlay gerber file. How do I get rid of the bottom logos?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have that logo somewhere in your design files. What you could do is switch to the overlay layer in the PCB design editor, press "shift S" to show only the top overlay layer, then go to "Edit" -> "Select" -> "Outside Area" (shortcut E-S-O) and drag the selection tool around the board. This will select any of the top overlay that exists *outside* of the board. Then just hit the "delete" key and it should delete the logo. This is assuming it is made out of primitives on the top overlay layer. If it's part of a component instead then you will need to determine which one (go through your libraries) and follow the same procedure as above but in the footprint editor.

Comment: I did what you suggest, after I drag the selection tool around the board, I didnt see anything outside the board. Also the logo is not part of any components.

Comment: Since you're looking at a Gerber in Camtastic also make sure you don't have any unwanted mechanical layers in the output job selected to "add to all plots".

Comment: @yxing The point of "select outside area" is to select anything that may be off-screen. Due to how the origin is set up in Altium it is possible for primitives to be outside of the visible work area, and there is no way to access them manually or actually see them. The select outside area should select it though, and if you click "delete" it will delete them.

Comment: The logo also appears (in a smaller size) on your board. Not too far from U1. So, see how / why / what added the logo there. Work backwards from there.

Comment: @DerStrom8 It worked, thank you so much

Comment: @yxing Glad to hear it! =)